# TypeError between two floats

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

So I'm trying to set conditional column coloring for my excel file using Openpyxl. Here's my code:

```
for cols in ws2.iter_cols(min_col=10, max_col=10, min_row=67, max_row=83):
    for cell in cols:
        if (cell.value > 0.35):
            cell.fill = PatternFill(fgColor="FFC000", patternType = 'solid')
```

But I just get an error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I checked types of `cell.value` and `0.35` - both are `float`. What can I do?

Comment: You data may have `Null` values as in your `cell.value`

Comment: Are you *very* sure that the TypeError is referring to the line you present in your question? You say you have checked the types and they are both float. But the interpreter has checked them too, and says that one of them is a string. And, for the line that it is complaining about, *the interpreter is always right*.

Comment: @BoarGules I have selected this specific part of code and executed it and got the same error message...

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I still say the interpreter is right about the types, and you are mistaken. Put a type check in your loop before doing the comparison and print the result.

Comment: the code just tells you what's there, and whenever you see an error message, your first assumption should be that you made a mistake. Maybe the first value of cell is a float, but there's atleast one value that's a string. Also, you're sure the error is in this line yeah?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try:
    if (float(cell.value) > 0.35):
        ...
except:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following:

```
cell_value = cell.value
if isinstance(cell_value, (int, float)) and (cell.value > 0.35):
    cell.fill = PatternFill(fgColor="FFC000", patternType = 'solid')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem resides in the fact that the column you are iterating isn't composed of all floats! Check the type of each element.